# DataTables .draw() not firing properly

Tags: jquery, datatables

Okay, so I have a DataTable that I'm trying to re-render when the clear button is clicked.

When I filter the table through my custom, filters, it works as expected. However, when I click 'Clear' all the inputs are cleared as expected, but the table doesn't get redrawn. Rather, the table still displays 'No Matching Records Found'. There are no errors being thrown in the console and the same code works in another template.

Any thoughts?

```
var table = $('#pages').DataTable({
  'ordering': true,
  "columnDefs": [
    { "name": "title", "targets" : 0},
    { "name": "path", "targets" : 1 },
    { "name": "created", "targets" : 2 },
    { "name": "updated", "targets" : 3 },
    { "name": "creator", "targets" : 4 },
    { "name": "templateName", "targets" : 5 },
    { "name": "status", "targets" : 6 },
    { "name": "includeOnMenu", "targets" : 7 },
  ],
    "dom": 'tip'  
});
$('.clear-filter').click(function() {
  $("#filter :input").each(function() {
    this.value = "";
  });
  table.draw();
});
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I include a .column.search('') before the .draw(), it will work. `table.columns(1).search('').draw();` `table.columns(0).search('').draw();` will not work.

Comment: Try `table.rows().invalidate().draw()` instead.

Comment: I get 'invalidate' is not a function.

Comment: See [rows().invalidate()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.invalidate%28%29) for more information, it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `table.destroy();` immediately before `table.draw();`. It's likely that you're "filtering" somehow before you do the table draw, which is causing this problem. `table.destroy();` will take out any filtering and then you can draw from scratch.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. There was filtering happening before and .destroy() seems to take care of it. What is strange to me is that the exact same code works on another page.

Comment: Glad it worked. As far as the other page, tough to say what is happening without seeing all the code, but I'd guess that the filtering isn't happening as you think it is. Maybe it's applying to a different table or something.

Answer (score 7):

I was having a very similar problem. This worked for me:

```
table.rows().invalidate().draw()
```