# Resfresh Datatable after ajax funcfion

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatable

my Datatable is not redrawing eventhoug I'm  calling the `.draw();` function...

My HTML:

```
{Contactos}
                <tr>
                    <td>{IdContacto}</td>
                    <td >{NomeContacto}</td>
                    <td>{NumeroContacto}</td>
                    <td class="IdContacto" data-id="{IdContacto}"><a style="color: white; margin-left: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditNumber" type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <i style="color: white; padding-right: 6px;" class="fa fa-edit"></i>Editar</a><a style="color: white; margin-left: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteNumber" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <i style="color: white; padding-right: 6px;" class="fa fa-trash"></i>Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>
                {/Contactos}
```

This is my JS:

```
function InsertPhoneNumber(){
var Nome = document.getElementById("Nome").value;
var Numero = document.getElementById("Numero").value;

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost/projeto/index.php/Backoffice_Controller/InserirContactos',
  data: {Nome: Nome, Numero: Numero},
  success: function (response) {
    NumberTable.draw();
    console.log("success");
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response){
    console.log("error");
    console.log(response); 
  }
});
}
```

Datatables initialization:

```
var NumberTable = $('#table_id').DataTable({

"bPaginate": false,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bFilter": true,
"bInfo": false,
"bAutoWidth": false,
"searching": false, 
 });
```

It prints me out the succeess message, and inserts the data to my database, but it doesn't gives me any error, nether redraws my table, any help pls?

Comment: Provide more details what you are doing?

Comment: Different libraries implement the `draw` method. Also, `DataTable` is ambiguous. Do you mean this [draw](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())? If so, read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31323520/5247200)

Comment: I'm inserting data into my datatable, and it goes very well, and if I refresh my page, the data apears, but I want my Table to redraw all alone, but it wont ;-;

Comment: @David That's it, but it ain't working with me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [draw-not-working-what-do-i-do-wrong](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40239/draw-not-working-what-do-i-do-wrong)

Comment: @David Still not working

Comment: What is its data source? You aren't updating anything in the success callback before you call draw(). Has that already happened somewhere before you sent the ajax request, or are you using server side processing?

Comment: @Don'tPanic My data source is my database! Before the success callback I have an JQuery function that via post method sends my data to my database, and I fetch my data into my Datatable!

Comment: Can you show the code that initializes the datatable, and the rest of the ajax request? The example you have so far seems to be a bit too minimal to really see how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Already updated my question! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Oh, good. But I meant the JavaScript code that initializes `NumberTable`. Can we see that as well, please?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Done! Sorry forgotten about that xD

Comment: No worries. Okay, here's what it looks like to me: you aren't using server side processing for the datatable. It's just populated with data when you load the page initially, which is why you do see it when you refresh the page. Calling `draw()` redraws the datatable, but there's no new data for it to display because that only gets loaded when the page loads. So you either need to change your datatable to use server side processing, which is kind of a pain on the server side IIRC, or just use jquery to append a row with the new values before calling `draw()`.